# Zurb Foundation grid height

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

im beginner in web-site development, and i using foundation framework.
And i have a little problem with the grid. You can see my screenshot with my problem. How i can to move left bottom block to this position?

[image]

```
    <section class="row">
  <article class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
    <div class="panel">
      <h2><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit minima impedit, eius maiores distinctio beatae. Culpa hic ducimus atque sint, quae voluptatem numquam similique neque ea saepe, minima, inventore eum?</p>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/800x100" alt="">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Works</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Company</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
      </ul>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis assumenda ad necessitatibus odio quae eum soluta, autem quos natus nisi aperiam beatae fugiat odit vel. Animi, assumenda unde quidem inventore.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio modi velit, recusandae quis veritatis ut beatae ipsum. Ab voluptate aperiam omnis nihil placeat. Dolorum veniam molestias doloribus, neque voluptatibus? Sed.</p>
    </div>        
  </article>

  <article class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
    <div class="panel">
      <h2><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis assumenda ad necessitatibus odio quae eum soluta, autem quos natus nisi aperiam beatae fugiat odit vel. Animi, assumenda unde quidem inventore.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio modi velit, recusandae quis veritatis ut beatae ipsum. Ab voluptate aperiam omnis nihil placeat. Dolorum veniam molestias doloribus, neque voluptatibus? Sed.</p>
    </div>        
  </article>

  <article class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
    <div class="panel">
      <h2><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis assumenda ad necessitatibus odio quae eum soluta, autem quos natus nisi aperiam beatae fugiat odit vel. Animi, assumenda unde quidem inventore.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio modi velit, recusandae quis veritatis ut beatae ipsum. Ab voluptate aperiam omnis nihil placeat. Dolorum veniam molestias doloribus, neque voluptatibus? Sed.</p>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum nisi doloribus sed earum temporibus. Libero reprehenderit perferendis nemo, minus deserunt dignissimos amet tempora enim placeat. Dolorem laboriosam, ipsum iste nisi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur, placeat. Aliquid beatae corporis magni. Unde maiores, sit perspiciatis atque sed architecto quos pariatur repudiandae animi dolores quisquam. Quasi, suscipit, pariatur.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt voluptates corporis accusamus fugit placeat praesentium quam debitis ipsam perferendis, consequuntur, labore voluptate dolorum pariatur officiis, veniam, consectetur cumque nisi mollitia?</p>
    </div>        
  </article>

    <article class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
    <div class="panel">
      <h2><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis assumenda ad necessitatibus odio quae eum soluta, autem quos natus nisi aperiam beatae fugiat odit vel. Animi, assumenda unde quidem inventore.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio modi velit, recusandae quis veritatis ut beatae ipsum. Ab voluptate aperiam omnis nihil placeat. Dolorum veniam molestias doloribus, neque voluptatibus? Sed.</p>
    </div>        
  </article>


    <article class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
    <div class="panel">
      <h2><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis assumenda ad necessitatibus odio quae eum soluta, autem quos natus nisi aperiam beatae fugiat odit vel. Animi, assumenda unde quidem inventore.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio modi velit, recusandae quis veritatis ut beatae ipsum. Ab voluptate aperiam omnis nihil placeat. Dolorum veniam molestias doloribus, neque voluptatibus? Sed.</p>
    </div>        
  </article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason it is that way is because of the way you're using foundation column layout.
You've used small-12 medium-6 columns class on articles, which mean that each column will occupy half of the screen ( on medium devices, because of medium-6 class). Each column has a display:block rule which will lay it out as in your image. In order of achieving what you want to achieve, you need to move part of the mark-up , you want to display underneath upper panel, to inside of this specific article with class small-12 medium-6 columns.
I got modified mark-up for that:

```
<section class="row">
  <article class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
    <div class="panel">
      <h2><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit minima impedit, eius maiores distinctio beatae. Culpa hic ducimus atque sint, quae voluptatem numquam similique neque ea saepe, minima, inventore eum?</p>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/800x100" alt="">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Works</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Company</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
      </ul>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis assumenda ad necessitatibus odio quae eum soluta, autem quos natus nisi aperiam beatae fugiat odit vel. Animi, assumenda unde quidem inventore.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio modi velit, recusandae quis veritatis ut beatae ipsum. Ab voluptate aperiam omnis nihil placeat. Dolorum veniam molestias doloribus, neque voluptatibus? Sed.</p>
    </div> 


    <div class="panel">
      <h2><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis assumenda ad necessitatibus odio quae eum soluta, autem quos natus nisi aperiam beatae fugiat odit vel. Animi, assumenda unde quidem inventore.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio modi velit, recusandae quis veritatis ut beatae ipsum. Ab voluptate aperiam omnis nihil placeat. Dolorum veniam molestias doloribus, neque voluptatibus? Sed.</p>
    </div>        
  </article>

  <article class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
    <div class="panel">
      <h2><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis assumenda ad necessitatibus odio quae eum soluta, autem quos natus nisi aperiam beatae fugiat odit vel. Animi, assumenda unde quidem inventore.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio modi velit, recusandae quis veritatis ut beatae ipsum. Ab voluptate aperiam omnis nihil placeat. Dolorum veniam molestias doloribus, neque voluptatibus? Sed.</p>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
    <div class="panel">
      <h2><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis assumenda ad necessitatibus odio quae eum soluta, autem quos natus nisi aperiam beatae fugiat odit vel. Animi, assumenda unde quidem inventore.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio modi velit, recusandae quis veritatis ut beatae ipsum. Ab voluptate aperiam omnis nihil placeat. Dolorum veniam molestias doloribus, neque voluptatibus? Sed.</p>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum nisi doloribus sed earum temporibus. Libero reprehenderit perferendis nemo, minus deserunt dignissimos amet tempora enim placeat. Dolorem laboriosam, ipsum iste nisi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur, placeat. Aliquid beatae corporis magni. Unde maiores, sit perspiciatis atque sed architecto quos pariatur repudiandae animi dolores quisquam. Quasi, suscipit, pariatur.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt voluptates corporis accusamus fugit placeat praesentium quam debitis ipsam perferendis, consequuntur, labore voluptate dolorum pariatur officiis, veniam, consectetur cumque nisi mollitia?</p>
    </div>        
  </article>

    <!-- <article class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
    <div class="panel">
      <h2><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis assumenda ad necessitatibus odio quae eum soluta, autem quos natus nisi aperiam beatae fugiat odit vel. Animi, assumenda unde quidem inventore.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio modi velit, recusandae quis veritatis ut beatae ipsum. Ab voluptate aperiam omnis nihil placeat. Dolorum veniam molestias doloribus, neque voluptatibus? Sed.</p>
    </div>        
  </article> -->


    <article class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
    <div class="panel">
      <h2><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis assumenda ad necessitatibus odio quae eum soluta, autem quos natus nisi aperiam beatae fugiat odit vel. Animi, assumenda unde quidem inventore.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio modi velit, recusandae quis veritatis ut beatae ipsum. Ab voluptate aperiam omnis nihil placeat. Dolorum veniam molestias doloribus, neque voluptatibus? Sed.</p>
    </div>        
  </article>
</section>
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

in css file try this: 

    `ul` 
    `{`
        `float :left;`
    
`}`
`li`
`{`
  `float: right;`
`}`

Comment: Thank you for answer, but it don't help:( I'm lookin for somethink like a Mansory plugin. Any ideas?

Comment: use class pull-left it will work [see here](https://gist.github.com/geksilla/6543145)